# Casting class to its implemented interface

Tags: java, interface, casting

What is the purpose of the ability to cast to interface?

I have that interface

```
public interface Iperson{ 
 String getTitle();
 int getID();
}
```

I have a class implementing it, e.g.

```
public class Person implements Iperson{

    public Person(){...}

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
    return 'aaa';
    }

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return '111';
    }    
}
```

In another class I have a function with the signature:

```
public boolean insert(Iperson somePerson)
```

What are the differences calling `insert(somePerson)` when `somePerson` is an instance of `Person` and when `somePerson` is a casted `(Iperson)Person`?

and when would one use the second option ?

Comment: A `Person` doesn't need to be cast to an `Iperson`. It *is* one. An unknown implementation of `Iperson` could be cast to a `Person` though. And the result of that depends on whether the cast is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely nothing.

When you pass an object to a method, it is cast to the type of argument which the function requires. In this case, since you pass a `Person` to `insert()`, the Person is cast as an `IPerson`.

If `Person` did not implement `IPerson`, then you could not pass it to `insert()`. However, since `Person` implements `IPerson`, it is implicitly cast to an `IPesrson` when it is passed to the `insert(IPerson)` function.

Answer (score 3):

Semantically, there is no difference. When you don't cast explicitly, an implicit upcast is performed.

Note that in some circumstances an explicit cast may be required to resolve an ambiguity:

```
public class Clazz {

    interface IOne {}
    interface ITwo {}

    static class C implements IOne, ITwo {}

    static void foo(IOne arg) {}
    static void foo(ITwo arg) {}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        foo(new C());        // ERROR: foo is ambiguous
        foo((IOne)new C());  // OK
        foo((ITwo)new C());  // OK
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of an Interface is so you can communicate with objects via that interface. For example, let's say you have three classes. `Car`, `Bus` and `Truck`. Those three classes implement the `Vehicle` interface. Instead of having methods like:

```
public void doSomething(Car car) {} 
public void doSomething(Bus bus) {} // etc
```

You can refer to them as their common interface.

```
public void doSomething(Vehicle v)
```

What this also means is that you can insert new classes, and still use this method. Provided that those classes implement the `Vehicle` interface, they can be passed to this method without changing an iota of code in the `doSomething` method. This is known as [Loose Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) and is a desirable feature in code.

Example Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Absolutly no difference!! You can remove the cast by the way!!
You can pass to the insert method a type of Person or Iperson or any object passing the "IS A" rule. So you can pass another type of IPerson (An employee which also implements Iperson for instance) or even a type of class that inherits from Person.
Having the IPerson as a type of argument in the insert method let you pass any of these types to the insert method. You are not obliged to pass only Persons type for example.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you can't access methods that are not in the interface but in the implementation class without casting it back to the implementing class.

Answer (score 0):

with the method call `public boolean insert(Iperson somePerson)` you can use *any* class that implements the `Interface Iperson` (so not only `Person`).

Now when you are callin `insert(somePerson)` the method gets an instance of `Person` but at the same time that instance is actually also an instance of `Iperson` (so to speak). So that insert method can use the methods and properties of the parameter `somePerson`, that it expects it to have. If you where to cast `somePerson` first to be a `Person`, then the method knows it can use all properties of the `Iperson` interface and every additional stuff you implemented in `Person` can be ignored (because it is not needed).

So basically if you can call `insert( somePerson)` without casting `somePerson` then don't cast (it would be useless).